# Javascript code to access Firebase jwt name

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In a Firebase database, I have the following:

```
books-4de62
 |
[-]-- Albany
       |
      [-] -- -KvcbdqFnnhC0WwnjciM
               |
               |-- "bookname": "Car repairs"
               |-- "available": "yes"
```

I can get a reference to Albany OK using:

```
var dbRef = new Firebase("https://books-4de62.firebaseio.com/");
var albanyRef = dbRef.child('Albany');
```

If I hardcode the `-KvcbdqFnnhC0WwnjciM` into the path using

```
var bookRef = albanyRef.child('/-KvcZj0urOutVNlq4w-r/');
```

I can then read the booknam, available data OK

Q. In js, how can I obtain the jwt name of `-KvcbdqFnnhC0WwnjciM` ? so I don't have to hardcode it?

Comment: I guess what I am really looking for is a way to read the postId